# Javascript Shorthand - What Does the '||' Operator Mean When Used in an Assignment?

Tags: javascript

I just took a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547998/javascript-jquery-time-format/3548350#3548350), and I noticed the following line of javascript code:

```
hrs = (hrs - 12) || 12;
```

My Question:

> What does the '||' operator mean when
>   used in an assignment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, the code assigns 12 to hrs if hrs-12 = 0 (as JavaScript sees it, 0 = false).

More generally, it assigns the latter value to the variable if the former value evaluates to 0, the empty string, null, undefined, etc.

Comment: More specifically it would be if hrs12 <= 0. I mean, who knows how hrs is being set originally?

Comment: @Casey: not so, *ToBoolean* on negative numbers results in *true*, so really it will only assign 12 to `hrs` if `hrs-12 = 0` as the answer says.

Comment: @Casey: It would only be `12` if `hrs - 12 == 0` (or some other falsey value). If it is less than `0`, it would be considered "true", and `hrs` would be assigned the negative value.

Answer (score 7):

It always means the same: *logical OR*

It's a common trick that makes use of type casting. Many non-boolean expressions evaluate to false. It's the same as this:

```
hrs = (hrs-12)
if(!hrs){
    hrs = 12;
}
```

And the if() works because 0 casts to false. It's also used to deal with undefined variables:

```
function foo(optionalValue){
    var data = optionalValue || "Default value";
}
foo();
foo("My value");
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of if `hrs-12` evaluates to `0`, the person wants `hrs` to be assigned `12` since `0` is not suitable.

Since `0` evaluates to false, the expression becomes `false || 12`, in which case `12` would be chosen since it's truthy.

Answer (score 2):

It means "If the first half of the expression is false, then use the second half instead."

Practically in this example, it means that `hrs` will be set to `hours-12`, unless `hours-12` is zero, in which case it will `hrs` will be set to `12`.

Answer (score 1):

It means ["short circuit or"](http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php). I.e. if the first part of the expression is false use the second instead. Wikipedia has [an article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on this with syntax for a number of languages.

Answer (score 1):

It means if hrs - 12 is evaluated to false (false, null, undefined, NaN, '', 0), then 12 will be assigned to hrs.