# What does this bit of code mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Shorthand - What Does the '||' Operator Mean When Used in an Assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511301/javascript-shorthand-what-does-the-operator-mean-when-used-in-an-assignme)

`var variable = obj1 || obj2;`

Does it mean this?

```
var variable;

if (obj1)
{
    variable = obj1;
}
else if (obj2)
{
    variable = obj2:
}
```

Is it considered bad practise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Shorthand - What Does the '||' Operator Mean When Used in an Assignment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511301/javascript-shorthand-what-does-the-operator-mean-when-used-in-an-assignme) and [JavaScript || operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378619/javascript-operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`||` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) returns its left hand side if resolves to be a true value, otherwise it returns its right hand side.

So it means the same as:

```
var variable;
if (obj1){
    variable = obj1;
} else {
    variable = obj2:
}
```

Note *else*, **not**, *else if*.

It is a common pattern and not usually considered bad practise.

The gotcha is that you need to be sure you want `if (obj)` and not `if (typeof obj !== "undefined")`.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, that's what it means, and it's good practice

`||` is a logical OR, so if `obj1 = false` you get `false OR obj2` so the variable equals obj2

Answer (score 0):

## How || expression works

The expression `a || b` value is determined by the last partial evaluated to determine Boolean truth.

`false || 1` is evaluated as `1` is the last one evaluated.

`true || 0` is evaluated as `true` as it is the last one evaluated.

## How obj is evaluated in Boolean context

For an object in the context of Boolean value, object is evaluated to `true` **unless null**. It means even `{} === true`.

Combine the above two explanation, `var variable = obj1 || obj2` assigns the first none null object from `obj1` and `obj2` to `variable`.